# Installed Ubuntu and now cannot Boot into it!

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, system-installation, uefi

I installed Ubuntu in my new machine.Before installing I made the following changes

1. turned off the fast startup option in windows 8.1
2. changed the boot to legacy supported
3. changed preference to legacy first

now Ubuntu boots just fine..but windows pops up an error saying the following  message/error

```
status: 0xc000000f

an error occurred while reading your boot configuration data
```

so now to solve this I changed the boot preference to uefi first and now grub does not show up and I cant boot into Ubuntu. How to solve this problem as I can not change my boot preferences everytime. Please Help me out as soon as possible..

Comment: possible duplicate of [0xc000000f error when starting Windows from Grub](http://askubuntu.com/questions/577751/0xc000000f-error-when-starting-windows-from-grub)

Comment: I'm no Windows expert, but it *looks like* this MS Q&A entry is relevant; there is a step by step workaround: 
http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-system/windows-7-after-grub-bcd-0xc000000f/4a42140a-7ce5-4c53-9c4e-9d5fd6372be9

Comment: I do not have a windows repair disk disk are there any other ways??

Comment: I don't know - but note that you can probably get replacement disks from your PC's manufacturer.

Comment: If you do not have a repair disk you can torrent an iso (you don't need a cracked or pirated version as you do not need to reinstall) and use that as described in Tobia Tesan's duplicate answer

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your BIOS was set as UEFI first when you installed Ubuntu, set it back to UEFI first and then boot using the [´boot-repair`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) CD. It's an Ubuntu-based boot disk that you can download. Once booted select automatic repair. It should fix your grub and allow dual boot again for both Windows and Ubuntu.

Comment: Could you please review my [edits](http://askubuntu.com/posts/605190/revisions) and also review the [editing help](http://askubuntu.com/editing-help) to improve the readability of your questions in the future... ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Your steps #2 and #3 were mistakes. They opened the door for more complex (and unnecessary) boot paths. The Ubuntu installer does a poor job of recognizing potential dual-boot problems, so the extra options end up being extra options to create problems, nothing more.

Hatterman's suggestion will probably work. Another option is to reset your firmware to *not* support BIOS/CSM/legacy-mode booting and re-install Ubuntu. A third is to boot the existing Ubuntu installation using the USB flash drive or CD-R version of my [rEFInd boot manager](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) and then install the rEFInd Debian package or PPA. If you do more EFI installations in the future, [do it the right way](http://www.rodsbooks.com/linux-uefi/) from the start.