# How do I remove the Ubuntu entry from the boot menu?

Tags: boot, uninstall

I had to remove Ubuntu manually by removing it folders on my hard drive since the uninstall.exe wasn't opening.

Everything is fine so far. But when I restart my PC and hit <kbd>F12</kbd> to see the boot menu, I still see the Ubuntu entry there. So how do I remove it without reinstalling my PC ? Also I have no USB flash drive.
I can ignore it but if it's possible to remove it, i would give it a try :).
I have tried already to download manually the Ubuntu uninstall.exe and open it. But nothing happens when I click on it.

I am using windows 10 64bit by the way.

Comment: You just want to remove the Ubuntu entry from the boot menu, or do you want to get rid of the boot menu altogether. Clarify, and if the latter: https://askubuntu.com/questions/577751/0xc000000f-error-when-starting-windows-from-grub

Answer (score 0):

I think your pc is UEFI, where your Ubuntu EFI Boot Entry is still there. Search for a tool like `efibootmgr` for your Windows OS to remove Ubuntu EFI boot entry from EFI Boot List.